# How to verify RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature generated from .NET in browser frontend?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, .net-6.0, digital-signature

I have the following task and problem:

- a payload is signed in a .NET 6 application (web service, actually the *hash* of the payload is signed, but I'll try to simplify this here)
- payload and signature are retrieved by a web application via JavaScript
- the signature should be validated using JavaScript in the browser
- **Problem**: signature validation fails

The .NET part roughly looks like this (condensed to the important parts):

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
{
    var privateKeyPem = File.ReadAllText(pemPath, Encoding.UTF8);
    rsa.ImportFromPem(privateKeyPem.ToCharArray());
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
    rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
    var SIGNATURE = rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(PAYLOAD);
}
```

Now `SIGNATURE` and `PAYLOAD` are passed over to the JavaScript app running in the browser, to be verified there.

*Note 1: the `jwk` structure below is generated from the public key PEM ([as shown e.g. here](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/01/10/x509-pkcs8-pem-key-to-jwks-node/)) of the key pair used to generate the signature*

*Note 2: I also tried `pkcs8` as first parameter for [crypto.subtle.importKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey), plus public key PEM as second param, but this also did not work out*

```
const publicKey = crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "jwk",
  {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "n": "<lots of chars>",
    "e": "AQAB"
},
  {
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    hash: { name: "SHA-256" },        
  },
  false,
  ["verify"]
);
const isSignatureValid = await crypto.subtle.verify({
  name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
  hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
}, publicKey, SIGNATURE, PAYLOAD);

// isSignatureValid === false
```

**The verification fails.**

I checked the content of signature and payload passed to `verify` and they contain the same bytes as in the .NET world. Yet verification fails.

Now I'm not a crypto pro so I'm not sure if I am making basic mistakes here.

Is my assumption wrong that verification should succeed? What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: In the currently posted code there are many possible causes for the problem, inconsistent keys, wrong identifiers, wrong encodings etc. You should post test data, a non-production key pair, message and signature (PKCS#1 v1.5 is deterministic, so a signature comparison is possible). Then there is something to work with. Also it is not clear from both snippets how `SIGNATURE` and `PAYLOAD` are encoded/decoded. Complete the snippets to this effect.

Comment: @Topaco That's a well-formulated comment, thank you. My hope was that there is a well known incompatibility that is not yet known to me that people will point out. If that is not the case the only way forward is a minimal repro, as you say. Right now I'm still hoping to get away lazy...

Answer (score 0):

Decryption works for me (using my own test data and appropriate encoding/decoding), if:

- in the C# code `PAYLOAD` is hashed with SHA-256 and the hash is passed to `CreateSignature()` (in contrast to WebCrypto, there is no implicit hashing on the C# side).
- in the WebCrypto code the `await` operator is used for `importKey()` (probably a typo).

---

Note that the C# code without hashing is not compliant with the [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2) scheme from RFC8017. Since WebCrypto does not allow signing without hashing, the fix must be done on the C# side.

Regarding the key import: WebCrypto supports the import of the public DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. As format [`spki`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#parameters) must be specified (`pkcs8` is for private keys). If the key is PEM encoded (*-----BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-----*), a conversion to DER is required (for this, header, footer and all line breaks must be removed and the rest must be Base64 decoded).